# How to use IntervalAutoMode.FixedCount

Tags: .net, asp.net, charts

I am trying to use the Microsoft Chart controls in a Windows forms application.

I want the Y-axis to always show 6 intervals. The length of every interval should be autocomputed. I think this should be easy by setting

```
area.AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.FixedCount;
```

But I can't get it to work - the number of intervals varies. What property should I set to always have 6 intervals drawn in the chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the Axis.Interval property. I would adjust the range(Max-Min) to a value divisible by seven to ensure you have 6 intervals.

Comment: Any other way without changing Max and Min?